# Highcharts wrap is not a function

Tags: highcharts

After a while, I want to get rid of the errors in the browser console. I searched this case on the internet and found nothing.

```
Uncaught TypeError: wrap is not a function
at highcharts-more.src.js:1141
at _registerModule (highcharts-more.src.js:26)
at highcharts-more.src.js:365
at highcharts-more.src.js:20
at highcharts-more.src.js:22
```

I am using **Highcharts JS v8.0.0**.

Comment: Hi @Ali, Could you reproduce that problem in some online code editor? The `wrap` method works fine with the newest Highcharts version: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4753/

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you made sure that all required .js files are referenced properly?

Comment: @ppotaczek Long time past project. I don't know after which code this happened.

Comment: @Steve, I try in Mozilla, But there was error.
`    <script src="/assets/scripts/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/scripts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/scripts/highcharts-localization.js"></script>`
Anything else?

Comment: @Ali, I do not see your code, so it is hard to say anything. You need debug to find out which part of your code is causing the error.

Comment: I found the problem. highcharts-more version was 8.0.0 and highstock version was 7.2.1. That was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

**Highcharts-more** version was 8.0.0 and **highstock** version was 7.2.1.

That was the problem.